# Cant connect to Tomcat6 running on Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6

I am trying to stand up tomcat6 and just view the default page.  Everything is installed and running correctly (or so it seems).  I start the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

and everything starts up fine.

```
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6
   ...done.
```

When I run a netstat, I can see that it is listening like expected on port 8080.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43521         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.65:40912      65.5.149.13:25          SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.65:22         99.44.242.76:50769      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    272 192.168.1.65:22         99.44.242.76:50552      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
```

But anytime I try to go to the X.X.X.X:8080, the page times out because the server is not responding.  I look in the logs and there are no errors.  I would be happy to post the logs, but they just have normal start up stuff.  So I know that the server is running, and I know that I am pointed at the right place, but in between the 2 something is configured wrong.  Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accessing remotely to that server? Try to check if there is any proxy, subnet or something that makes the packages not to reach the destination.
First try to access to the server locally.

"http://Localhost:8080"

Then, from another computer check if ping works. if not, check if both are in the same domain

ADDED:

However if you have access to start tomcat you should be to test it locally:

remotelly:

```
traceroute -p 8080 your.server.ip
```

on the server:

```
traceroute -p 8080 localhost
```

Comment: It is headless, so I cant access the server locally.  Is there any way to do it from another machine on my home network?  Also how do I check if there is a proxy or a subnet?

Comment: ok, first try to ping the server, if it answers that means it is in the same subnet.
I am not network expert. I am sure someone else is gonna help you with that.
If it answer the ping, next step is check the port. Let me know

Comment: I added above more info of how to check a port status

Comment: On the server my traceroute returned `traceroute to localhost (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.033 ms  0.011 ms  0.009 ms`, but when I ran it from a different machine I just kept getting * * *.  The strange thing is when I ran the same traceroute, but on port 80 I got the same response, * * *.  I have a rails app running on that port that I can access from anywhere without a problem.

Comment: UPDATE:  I went to a friends house and did the traceroute outside of my home network and I got a normal traceroute for port 80.  Port 8080 gave me the same thing I got earlier, * * *.  The console output is `13 traceroute: wrote 192.168.1.65 52 chars, ret=-1
 * * *.  I did not have this console output from my home network.  
14  * * *
traceroute: sendto: No route to host
15 traceroute: wrote 192.168.1.65 52 chars, ret=-1`.  I did not have this console output from my home network.

Comment: It is not possible to ping a private IP from outside you local network. Internet does not route any package with private IP address like  192.168.x.x or 172.16.x.x, etc. Therefore you only can make further tests from within your work network, Unless you are able to connect to that network using a VPN (virtual private network).
You mention you have a rails App running on port 80 in the same server, right? How do you access to that app? do you do like www.myApp.net? In that case you should contact your system administrator to check the DNS server and the rules and alias defined.

Comment: The traceroute led me to the answer.  I am fairly new to unix and did not understand that command.  I had the port 8080 assigned to an old server, so I was being blocked at my router.  I changed the port forwarding and all was good.  Thanks.